# javascript execCommand('delete') not delete all selection div in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, contenteditable, rangy, execcommand

I try to write an editor with contenteditable & execCommand
Everything works fine on Firefox, but in chrome has an error with 'delete' command.

Please view bellow photo:

[image]

This is my code:

```
var $obj = $('#myBlockDivId');
var selection = rangy.getSelection();
if (selection.rangeCount > 0) selection.removeAllRanges();
var range = rangy.createRange();
range.selectNode($obj[0]);
selection.addRange(range);
range.select();
```

when i console log: rangy.getSelection().toHtml() ==> it's right

but when i call:

```
document.execCommand("delete", null, false);
```

it's fine on Firefox but not right on Chrome, the wrapper div is not being deleted.

How can i fix this? I have to use execCommand because it's support undo and redo function. so, i can't use jquery or javascript dom selector to remove div.

(I bad at English, someone please edit my question for more clearly, many thanks)

Comment: Can you post an example of the non-working code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: What is the error ? can you post it ?

Comment: Without an example of the code (especially the HTML), all of the answers will be guesses. Note that there is an answer using Stack Snippets. Please use the same, editing your question to include the HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try to do :
*(note the argument alone)*

```html
<span contentEditable>
 Select something here and after click on delete.
</span>
<input type="button" value="Delete selection" onclick="document.execCommand('delete')"/>
```

---

Acording to w3c.github.io on [Enabled commands](https://w3c.github.io/editing/execCommand.html#enabled-commands) :

> At any given time, a supported command can be either enabled or not. Authors can tell whether a command is currently enabled using queryCommandEnabled(). ***Commands that are not enabled do nothing***, as described in the definitions of the various methods that invoke commands.

Some helpfull links :

***w3c Unofficial Draft 15 October 2015***:

- [w3c execCommand](https://w3c.github.io/editing/execCommand.html)
- [w3c Deleting the selection](https://w3c.github.io/editing/execCommand.html#deleting-the-selection)
- [w3C The delete command](https://w3c.github.io/editing/execCommand.html#the-delete-command)

***Other ressources*** :

- [List of contenteditable Browser Inconsistencies](https://github.com/guardian/scribe/blob/master/BROWSERINCONSISTENCIES.md)
- [quirksmode.org test page](http://quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand/)

Hope this will help you !

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
document.execCommand("delete", false, null);
```

Instead of :

```
document.execCommand("delete", null, false);
```

Comment: I've try every thing i can, as you tell, and i've try document.execCommand("insertHtml", false, '<p></p>') to overwite old content, but not ok