# get highlighted text not the highlighted text value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a text editor where the user can change some text by highlight/select it and then click some button for delete or add a new char in it so I need to get that specific text

i have tried this `window.getSelection().toString()` but my problem is that ifIi have text that have two or more same words like `'dont click here or here'` and the user highlighted the second `'here'` lets say then i cant really know which one of these two words the user has highlighted

so i want to get the highlighted string not by value or i don't know how do i solve this problem
p.s. the text editor that i want to create is similar to this editor that i'm writing this question on

edit: my problem is not that i want to delete some string my problem is that i want to get the text not the value of the text so when i write 11111111111 and highlight only one of the 1s i can know exactly which one is highlighted

Comment: All the information is in the `Selection` object that `getSelection()` returns. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection

Comment: Why are you creating your own text editor? There are many libraries you can use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript execCommand('delete') not delete all selection div in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429105/javascript-execcommanddelete-not-delete-all-selection-div-in-chrome)

Comment: @prasanth nope i dont think so

Comment: @Barmar i just want to create my own

Comment: i think yes.see the first answer of the question .its same as you requirement its delete only selected text https://jsfiddle.net/fnwkpudr/

Comment: @prasanth That shows how to delete, but he also wants to modify the selection.

Comment: @R3ter check this edit only with `document.execCommand` .its have all the editor tools  [Codepen](https://codepen.io/chrisdavidmills/full/gzYjag/) and [documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Syntax)

Comment: ok, my problem is not that i want to delete some string my problem is that i want to get the text not the value of the text so when i write 11111111111 and highlight only one of the 1s  i can know exactly which one is highlighted

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested with `getSelection()` method and you can use `baseOffset` & `focusOffset` property to determine the position. **BaseOffset** counts & returns the number of character that the selection started & **FocusOffset** counts & returns the number of character where the selection end.

Here is an example:

```js
function getHighLightText() {
   let text = window.getSelection().toString();
   console.log(text); // log selected text
   //console.log(window.getSelection()); // log getSelection
   console.log(window.getSelection().baseOffset + ' - ' + window.getSelection().focusOffset); // log selection start & end offset.
}

document.onselectionchange = getHighLightText;
```

```html
<p id="p">111111111</p>
```

`

**Note:** Not tested with large text.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the position of the selected text with [`getRangeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/getRangeAt)

Demo:

```js
function getSel(el) {
  console.clear();
  var selObj = window.getSelection();
  var selection = selObj.toString();
  console.log(`Selected: ${selection}`);
  var selRange = selObj.getRangeAt(0);
  console.log(`from: ${selRange.startOffset}\nto: ${selRange.endOffset}`);
  console.log(el.textContent);
  el.textContent = `${el.textContent.substr(0, selRange.startOffset)} ***${el.textContent.substr(selRange.endOffset)}`;
};
```

```html
<div onmouseup="getSel(this)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
```